# For how many ordered pairs of positive integers $(x,y)$ is $x+2y = 100$?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

For how many ordered pairs of positive integers $(x,y)$ is $x+2y =
100$?

I'm thinking the answer is 16. Since it is x+2y=100 this implies that x is even. so x=2,4, 6, 8, 10, ..., 30, 32. There are 16ordered pairs.

Comment: Why are you stopping at $x=32$?

Comment: Why can't $x$ equal 34?

Comment: I believe the OP is thinking if $x > 32$ then $y < x$ and we will get pairs that have already been calculated.  But since these are *ordered* pairs that doesn't matter.  Also as $\{a, \frac {100-a}2\}\ne \{100 - 2a, a\}$ that reasoning is not valid.

Comment: I'm crazy lol I see how silly I was being now

Answer (score 2):

We have $x=100-2y=2(50-y)$ and so $x>0$ iff $y<50$.

Therefore, every value of $y=1,\dots,49$ works.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $x$ would be even. And the value will range from $2, 4, 6,... 98$. We end at 98 because that would give the minimum possible value of $ y$ which is $1$. So in total, there are $49$ ordered pairs.